# Why use a dot to execute the profile?

Tags: unix

I'm new to Linux. In the command below, why do I need to use a dot to execute the profile?

```
. ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Noufal mentioned, `.` is an alias for `source`.

By sourcing the file, all commands are executed within the context of your current bash session, which means that all environment variables which it exports will now be available to you.

If you run the script instead of source it, it is executed in a subshell and exported variables are not passed on to your session. In effect, that pretty much defeats the purpose of `.profile`.

As a demonstration, say you have the file `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# in test.sh
print "exporting HELLO"
export HELLO="my name is Paul"
```

If you execute it:

```
[me@home]$ bash test.sh
exporting HELLO
[me@home]$ echo $HELLO
```

Nothing gets printed out since `$HELLO` is not defined in your current session. However, if you source it:

```
[me@home]$ . test.sh
exporting HELLO
[me@home]$ echo $HELLO
my name is Paul
```

Then `$HELLO` will be available in your current session.

Comment: Great example, But in this command: cp /usr/local/1.txt . the does dot still represent the source? or it has a another meaning in this context

Comment: In that context, the dot means 'current directory'. Dot is an alias for source only when used as a command.

Comment: In general, the dot has 3 separate meanings depending on context. See http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/special-chars.html

Comment: programmers are so lazy they'll abbreviate everything.

Answer (score 4):

The period operator is an alias for the `source` command. Details [here](http://ss64.com/bash/period.html).

Comment: your link says:  >> ... source is a synonym for dot/period '.' in bash, but not in POSIX sh, so for maximum compatibility use the period. ... <<
I found that information useful

Answer (score 1):

Pretty hard to tell without more context, but one usage is the Bash-specific file `.bash_profile` to include the more generic (as far as Bourne shells go) file `.profile`, since when Bash finds the first, it won't load the second one by itself.